# How to call console app exe by batch file with a parameter?

Tags: c#

I want to execute my console application by a batch file..
actually how to do that? and if i want to pass parameter from batch file to this exe
is it do able?
my console app header like below:-

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
        string ls_FileExt = "", ls_FileName = "";
        DateTime ldt_CurrDateTime = System.DateTime.Now;
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\A");
//...
 }
```

By hero

Answer (score 2):

if your program is called `prog.exe`, and your batch file is `batch.cmd`, then you can write something like this in your batch file:

```
prog.exe %1 %2 %3 %4 %5
```

in this case, if you type in your console

```
batch my parameter list mwa ha ha
```

your program will be called like

```
prog.exe my parameter list mwa ha
```

(note that only first 5 parameters are passed to the exe).

Answer (score 1):

The same like if you do it from console:

Myexe.exe. parameter1 parameter2 \"parameter3\" parameter4 ....

Answer (score 0):

your question is very vague. if you want to know how to get the arguments passed to your application, they are in the "args" parameter of your Main method. is this what you were looking for??

Comment: I dont know the comment at batch file at all.. i try to call the exe with a parameter from a batch file but i dont know how to make it happen

Comment: post the batch file and tell us exactly where you get stuck